# Matrix containing ellipse

Tags: matrix, geometry

I have to make a matrix which contains elements in an ellipse shaped region, but I need to make ellipse region in such a way that larger axis of ellipse is inclined with angle θ with horizontal. With `Colorize` the matrix should look like this:

[image]

I have employed two ways so far for this:

- Use `Graphics`, followed by `MorphologicalComponents` and then use `Position` to get a list and then convert it into matrix.
- Write the equation of an inclined ellipse as `f[x,y] = 0` and then use condition `f[x,y] <= 0` and run it on matrix coordinates to get the list and then finally convert it into matrix.

However, these two methods are a bit slow and I would like to use something like `DiskMatrix` or any other way to make it faster.

Comment: Doesn't `MorphologicalComponents[
 Rasterize[Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, {2, 1}]], ImageSize -> 800]]` give a matrix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way, probably not the cleanest:

```
gr = Graphics[Rotate[Disk[{0, 0}, {4, 2}], Pi/6], ImageSize -> 250];
a  = Image[gr, "Bit", ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"] // ImageData;
a // Colorize
```

[image]

You can control the border size using [`PlotRangePadding`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) or [`ArrayPad`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArrayPad.html), for Graphics or absolute scaling.

This is not slow:

```
gr = Graphics[Rotate[Disk[{0, 0}, {4, 2}], Pi/6], ImageSize -> 5000];

Timing[a = Image[gr, "Bit", ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"] // ImageData;]

Dimensions[a]
```

> ```
> {0.140401, Null}
>
> {3714, 5000}
> ```

By comparison:

```
DiskMatrix[2154] // Dimensions // Timing
```

> ```
> {0.187201, {4309, 4309}}
> ```

So my method is faster than `DiskMatrix` for an output of the same size.

[`Binarize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Binarize.html) can be used directly on a `Graphics` expression but it appears to not be as fast.

Answer (score 6):

For a worst case scenario when your graphics broke down, and you are forced to work only with numbers

```
f[x_, y_, a_, b_] := (x + y)^2/a^2 + (x - y)^2/b^2
R = 10;
mat=Table[If[f[m, n, 2, 3] < R^2, Style[X, Red], O], {m, -2 R,2 R}, {n, -2 R, 2 R}];
Grid[mat, Spacings -> {0, 0}]
```

Change R, a, b to change the shape.

[image]

Its probably not very practical way, just added to give some different flavour!

**Controlling the angle**

The orientation can be controlled by the angle `q`.

```
f[x_, y_, a_, b_, q_] := (x Cos[q] + y Sin[q])^2/a^2 + (y Cos[q] - x Sin[q])^2/b^2
R = 10;
mat[a_, b_, q_] := Table[If[f[m, n, a, b, q] < R^2, Style[X, Red], O], {m, -2R,2 R}, {n, -2 R, 2 R}]

fig = Table[{Style[q, 20, Bold], Grid[mat[1, 2, q], Spacings -> {0, 0}]}, {q,0, Pi/2, Pi/6}];
TableForm[Transpose[fig]]
```

[image]

Comment: The inclusion of styling in the matrix generation itself obfuscates and slows the code.  I suggest refactoring this to produce a pure binary matrix first, for comparison to other methods.

Comment: indeed @Mr.Wizard, it goes like a turtle.

Answer (score 2):

Credit goes to @acl

```
MorphologicalComponents@
   Rasterize[Graphics[{Rotate[Disk[{0, 0}, {4, 2}], Pi/6]}], 
       ImageSize -> 30] /. (0) -> Style[0, Red] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: FYI: this is about 4.5X slower than the code in my answer.

Comment: note `Rasterize` does not (evidently) have an option to make a 1-bit image, so you end up with gray values at the edges of the ellipse. You could use `Round` instead of `MorphologicalComponents` however. (still a tad slower than `Image` ).